# Use Raw HTML/CSS With Text Input?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I include the ability to add custom html/css when inputting text via `<%= f.input :body %>`?

I'm making a company blog so only me the admin will have access to writing the blog posts so I don't have to worry about people inputting malicious code to break the site.

I tried `<%= f.input raw :body %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just save the unescaped html in a text attribute and display the results using `raw`.

`<%= f.text_area :body %>`

Then, to display the escaped html: `<%= raw @object.body %>`.